# adding Table or list of items to SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite called "Cars" and i have these titles:

```
|   ID   |   Type    |   Color   |
|:------:|:---------:|:---------:|
|    1   |  4 Wheel  |    Red    |       
|    2   |    Van    |    Blue   |
```

now i want to add another column call "Details" and "Details" has it own table like so

```
|   ID   |   Chair    |   Sensor   |
|:------:|:----------:|:----------:|
|    1   |    Brown   |    Yes     |
```

so i have to make separated table for that, is there any way that i can fit a table inside another table so i don't have to make separated table every time?

of course i have to make table, but i mean like something within the each item, so i don't have to look for it and don't make my table list messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any database tables are created depending on their relationship to the other thing?
I hear you say "What does he mean?"
For example just pretend I own a worldwide agricultural empire and I
want to keep track of livestock 
First of all I would break my database up into

- Country
- Holding (eg Ranch, Estancia, Cattle Station)
- cattle (Individual cow, bull etc)

Now because each country has many holdings
country and holding have a one to many relationship
and because each holding has many cattle holding and cattle have a 
one to many relationship
to place cattle and holding (Ranch) information into the same table would be just too messy and not smart.

### So now here's where the question gets answered

You said that you want one table inside another table the bad news is that you can't but you wouldn't want to because that's not how databases work and it wouldn't make sense if you could but the good news is that you can issue a query that will bind the 2 tables together into 1 query
In your case the query could go something like this

```
  SELECT * FROM Cars, Details WHERE Cars.Id = Details.Id
```

### Where to from here?

In order to sort this out I recommend

1. Download Firefox browser
2. On Firefox browser go tools -> addons and search for and download SQLite Manager, This will enable you to mock up your database and practice SQL on it
   3.Note that with SQLite the way to issue a query when unsing a langage such as java  is different
3. I suggest learning SQL from a book, a friend or a website such as  [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you want to `ALTER TABLE Cars ADD COLUMN Details {datatype};` to include the new attribute "Details". Then make the attribute a foreign key in the Cars table and have it referencing the Details table.

```
    ALTER TABLE Cars ADD COLUMN Details_id INTEGER REFERENCES Details(id);
```

Or, you can create the initial table with the foreign key in mind.

```
    CREATE TABLE Cars(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Type VARCHAR(25),
        Color VARCHAR(20),
        Details_id INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY(Details_id) REFERENCES Details(id),
    );
```